# Prevent striping of HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I am making an HTML editor in my application, which takes the HTML content from the database and copies it in an content editable DIV. But after making the changes, it strips the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, but keeps the body content.

How can I resolve the issue?

```
 document.getElementById('editHtmlView').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').value;
```

where #content has the content fetched from database.

```
<div id="editHtmlView" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Please show some code. Help us help you.

Comment: @JonathanLam edited.

Comment: you may wanna keep whatever gets removed in a variable, and add that back after the editing is finished when saving to database.

Comment: @boomcode If you're fetched content is its own document, with its own HTML tag, then you're best loading the content in an iframe. If for whatever reason this isn't an option, you should store the HTML and HEAD of the data coming in before it gets stripped out, then re-add it back when saving it to the database (if needed) - as Sharky suggests

Answer (score 1):

If you want the tags to show up as text, try changing `.innerHTML` to `.textContent`

`.innerHTML` tries to change the actual HTML in the div, which causes the browser to reject tags that don't make sense (like `<html>` tags inside a div). Setting content via `.textContent` preserves tags as text, and is more secure in general too.

Comment: ah, thought you were using jQuery; updated the answer.

Comment: @Steve OP did tag the question with jQuery so I assume you can answer using it.

Comment: @Steve This does copy the whole HTML content, but does not show editable preview, which i could get earlier.

Comment: @Steve I am comfortable using a jquery approach too.

Comment: It sounds like you want to build a WYSIWYG editor. I think it'd be difficult to inject HTML into a div and not have it strip out those tags. Perhaps an iframe is better? Or it might be easier to use a library. You can read more about using/building WYSIWYG editors in these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162540/contenteditable-div-vs-iframe-in-making-a-rich-text-wysiwyg-editor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426478/building-a-wysiwyg-editor